# Is every unitary matrix of the form $e^{A}$ where $A$ is skew-adjoint?

Tags: matrices, operator-theory

If (and only if) $A$ is a skew-adjoint matrix, then $e^{A}$ is unitary.  Can this be reversed?  In other words, can every unitary matrix be written as a matrix exponential?

Comment: See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_theorem_on_one-parameter_unitary_groups

Comment: You could diagonalize and take logs of the eigenvalues, so yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but not in a unique way. If $U$ is unitary, we can diagonalize it and write $U = VDV^{*}$ where $V$ is unitary and $D = \operatorname{diag}(e^{i\theta_1}, \dots, e^{i\theta_n})$ is diagonal. Set $A = \operatorname{diag}(i\theta_1,\dots,i\theta_n)$. Then $A$ is skew-adjoint and $e^A = D$ which also implies that

$$ e^{VAV^{*}} = e^{VAV^{-1}} = Ve^{A}V^{*} = VDV^{*} = U$$

and $VAV^{*}$ is also skew-adjoint (because $V$ is unitary). The fact that this is not unique can be seen already in the diagonal case because we can replace $A$ with $\operatorname{diag}(i(\theta_1 + 2\pi k_1), \dots, i(\theta_n + 2 \pi k_n))$ where $k_1,\dots,k_n \in \mathbb{Z}$.