# The form of an $n \times n$ unitary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, unitary-matrices

I recently came across this fact that [any $ 2 \times 2 $ unitary matrix can be expressed as $$ \begin{bmatrix} w & z \\ -\overline{z}e^{i\theta} & \overline{w}e^{i\theta}\end{bmatrix}$$ for some $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ and $w,z \in \mathbb{C}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/270109) I wanted to ask if there is any similar general form for $n \times n$ unitary matrices too.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is better to use $\overline z$ instead of $z*$ in order to talk about the conjugate of $z$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks. I have changed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any unitary matrix $\bf{U}$ can be written as $\exp(i\bf{H})$ where $\bf{H}$ is Hermitian. A brief explanation, where I use $\mathbf{A}^*$ to denote the conjugate transpose of a matrix $\bf{A}$.

$$\mathbf{U}\mathbf{U}^*=\mathbf{I}\\\exp(i\mathbf{H})\times\exp(i\mathbf{H})^*=\exp(i\mathbf{H})\times\exp(-i\mathbf{H}^*)=\exp(i\mathbf{H})\times\exp(-i\mathbf{H})\\\exp(i\mathbf{H})\times\exp(-i\mathbf{H})=\exp(i\mathbf{H}-i\mathbf{H})=\exp(\mathbf{0})=\mathbf{I}\\\therefore\mathbf{U}\mathbf{U}^*=\exp(i\mathbf{H})\times\exp(i\mathbf{H})^*\implies\exists\mathbf{H}:\mathbf{U}=\exp(i\mathbf{H})$$

Now in the last step, the "implies" part, this is a weak step: I don't think this is at all a rigorous proof, but I'm just trying to show that it can be true. According to Wikipedia, it is in fact true for every single unitary matrix.

The conjugate transpose of $\bf{H}$ is by definition also just $\bf{H}$, explaining one step, and the first step is true since in the expansion of the matrix exponential it is straightforward to see that $\exp(i\bf{H})^*$ is the same as $\exp(-i\bf{H})$ by some properties of the complex conjugate e.g. $\overline{a+b}=\overline{a}+\overline{b}$.

VERY importantly, note that I can only put the multiplication of two exponentials as one exponential in the second line since $i\bf{H}$ and $-i\bf{H}$ commute with one another. In general, $\exp(\bf A+B)\neq\exp(A)\times\exp(B)$ when $\bf A,B$ don't commute.

Comment: See here for a proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2229659/is-every-unitary-matrix-of-the-form-ea-where-a-is-skew-adjoint

Comment: Thank you for the proof

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This will help.

Comment: You’re welcome!